# Opening Chrome with Python / Mechanize

Tags: python, google-chrome, mechanize

I am trying to program an automation tool for an online game called travian.
I want to login using a python browser object (created by using the mechanise library). Once I have logged  in I want to open a real webbrowser (ie. chrome).

```
#here I create a mechanize browser object

b = mechanize.Browser()

#usually to login to the game you go to this 
# site and put in your login and password and press submit

server = 'http://ts4.travian.com/?lang=en'

#I am trying here to use a browser object to submit the form, 
#maybe there is a mistake here 

b.open(server)
b.select_form("login")
b.form["name"] = 'myAccount'
b.form["password"] = 'myPassword'
b.submit()

#once mechanise has submitted the form I want to 
#open the page in chrome that would  usually be 
#opened if I were to submit it by hand

gamePage = ("http://ts4.travian.com/dorf1.php")
webbrowser.open_new_tab(gamePage)
```

When I run this code it opens the login page, that is, the code that logs in to the game does not seem to have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an old question of mine. The the easiest way to do what I was trying to achieve is to use a class called Selenium.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
b.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3')]
```

before you open any URLs?

This will simulate Chrome on a Linux device.